# Trying to prove Quaternion function, looking for advice

Tags: quaternions

I'm trying to solve the Quaternion function:  $i^2 = j^2 =k^2 =ijk=-1$

I'm trying to solve it by myself since I found it quite interesting even though its far above and beyond Advanced Level syllabus, does anyone here have any advice on how to go about it? I can't really ask those around me as they have up to Advanced Level Knowledge.

Edit: my main stumbling block is proving $ijk=-1$

Comment: The formula you posted is basically the definition of quaternions. What is the "function" you are trying to "prove" or "solve"? The question is unclear.

Comment: what im trying to prove is that $ijk=-1$

Comment: What are your assumptions? $ijk=-1$ is part of the definition.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
& & i \\
& \nearrow & & \searrow \\
k & & \leftarrow & & j
\end{array}
$$
\begin{align}
\hline
\text{following} & \text{ the arrows} & \text{opposite} & \text{ direction} \\[6pt]
\hline
ij & = k & ji & = -k \\
jk & = i & kj & = -i \\
ki & = j & ik & = -j \\
\hline
\end{align}
The above is the multiplication table.

$$
ijk = (ij)k = (k)k = -1 \quad \text{or}\quad ijk = i(jk) = i(i) = -1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a definition of the $4$ dimensional algebra of the Quaternions. By definition,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{H} &= \{a + bi + cj + dk : a, b, c, d ∈ \mathbb{R}\} \\
\end{align}
Here, $i, j$ and $k$ are all square roots of $−1$ with relations

$$ij = k = −ji, jk = i = −kj, ki = j = −ik$$

These all follow from $$i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$$

And you can check these yourself.

Comment: thanks, this really helps

Comment: @MadMathWiz no problem, don't be downhearted over the down votes and votes to close. Keep reading!

Comment: thanks for your kind words, it means a lot